# Problemas con wifi y Error PCIe

Tags: linux

Hola acabo de instalar linux mint y me acabo de dar cuenta de que me va muy mal la conexión WiFi, necesito los instalar los drivers adecuados para mi tarjeta pero no lo encuentro. Mi tarjeta es : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

Y mi equipo es: HP Laptop 15-bs0xx
Y tengo linux mint 18 64 bits

Busqué por Internet e introduje este código en la terminal para probar si se solucionaba mi error : sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential. Pero no me funcionó

Además acabo de detectar un problema en mi portátil, a veces cuando inicio Linux me aparece un montón de veces sin parar:

AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 0] Receiver Error (First)

Eso me pasaba con Linux mint 19, luego instalé mint 18 y me sigue pasando.

Alguien me puede ayudar urgentemente por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Estaré encantado de ayudarte,

Primero tienes que tener los repositorios oficiales **non-free** de Linux Mint.

El archivo para editar lo puedes encontrar en: "/etc/apt/sources.list".

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Añadir los siguientes repositorios:

```sh
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ debian main upstream import
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest testing main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/security testing/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://debian.linuxmint.com/latest/multimedia testing main non-free
```

Después ejecuta:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt install git
```

Instala el siguiente programa:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/roopansh/rtl8723be_wifi
cd rtl8723be_wifi
bash rtl8723be.sh
```

Reinicia tu ordenador y comprueba que funciona todo correctamente.

Espero que sirva de ayuda :)